# How to create table depends on values from other table and depend on those values SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

As in title im searching a way to create new table. The table will be a table of contracts per month

```
create table NR1
(
  id         INTEGER not null,
  price      INTEGER,
  price2     INTEGER,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date   DATE,
  duration   NUMBER
)
```

depending on duration, i want to cut whole date from start_date to end_date into small month pieces, and put it as a row, for example if one row with duration 5 and starting date 2018-05-01, then i want to have in new table 5 rows with each month, so 2018-05-01, 2018-06-01, ..., 2018-10-01.

Can you tell me what should i use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view like this.

Sample rows

```
INSERT INTO NR1 (id,price,price2,start_date,end_date,duration) VALUES ( 1,20,40,DATE '2018-05-01',NULL, 5);
INSERT INTO NR1 (id,price,price2,start_date,end_date,duration) VALUES ( 2,30,60,DATE '2018-02-01',NULL, 6);
```

View

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_NR1 AS
SELECT id,price,price2,
    add_months(start_date,level - 1) AS start_date,
    last_day(add_months(start_date,level - 1) ) AS end_date
FROM
    nr1
CONNECT BY level <= duration
           AND PRIOR id = id
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3027d294cd3ed015cb6e91fd4f1426ef)

Comment: It's nice, i tried something with `WITH` statement, but your way create view that can be manipulated in next steps. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Look is it possible to put one more rows? for example: from `start_date` to `last day of month` and next row: from `first day of month` to `start_date +level`

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem you could create a trigger on your table and reference the fields of your table with respect to your requirements.